# How can I use LINQ on a List<T> where T doesn't have any nested elements?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 1 };
```

How can I use LINQ (inline), in the following manner:

```
foo.Any( bar => ... )
```

I am having trouble with the `...` portion as I am used to using LINQ where `bar` is an object with nested elements like the following:

```
class Roo {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public Roo() { }
}

.....

List<Roo> foo = new List<Roo>() { ... };
foo.Any( bar => bar.id == 3; )
```

Comment: Simple Any()? Or foo.Any(bar => bar);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` is the primitive type directly:

```
foo.Any( bar => bar > 1);
```

Think of LINQ extension method as `for` loops:

```
foreach(int bar in foo)
{

}
```

For objects:

```
foreach(Roo bar in foo)
{

}
```

I think this makes it easier for you.

Comment: Wow I was so overthinking this one.  Thank you  :)

Comment: @RonKlein I'm following the OP's naming of classes and variables.